# determine currently in contact using SprikeKit Contact Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Here is a code snippet I'm using in my `didBeginContact` delegate method:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

    for (Lasers *laser in self.lasers.spawnArray) {
        if (contact.bodyB == self.player.physicsBody && [contact.bodyA.node.name isEqual:laser.sprite.name]) {

            if ([self.lasers isDoneSpawning]) {
                if (!self.player1.isSuperPlayer) {
                    [self playerDied];
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

So, there are red laser beams that will kill the player if the player runs into them. If the player current has the `superPlayer` power-up activate then the player can run right through these red beams.

The code above works perfectly to achieve this, but when the player has the power-up active and stands right in the middle of the red beam and then the power-up is deactivated then the player will not die. The reason is that this method is only run when the initial contact between the two sprites begins.

I don't think there is a delegate method to determine if the sprites are currently in contact. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Maybe set the 'contactTestBitMask' to not contact the laser at the start of the power-up and then set it back when the power-up ends? I believe that will generate a 'didEndContact' and then a 'didBeginContact', allowing the appropriate code to come into play.

Comment: This worked! Post it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Sweet! I didn't post it as an answer because I couldn't confirm it without doing a decent amount of testing but since you did that I'll do it as an answer. Glad it worked.

Comment: You need to check if the player is bodyA and the laser is bodyB in didBeginContact as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `contactTestBitMask` to not contact the laser at the start of the power-up and then set it back when the power-up ends. That will generate a `didEndContact` and then a `didBeginContact`, allowing the appropriate code to come into play.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack but should achieve proper functionality...

Immediately after setting your Super power-up to end, Remove and re-add your laser beams.

This will signal a new didBeginContactEvent and should kill your player.

Comment: ha... I will try that but is certainly hacky!

Comment: In the end it was close, needed to add and remove the 'contactTestBitMask'